# Тире/дефис в сложных приложениях

Tags: пунктуация, приложение, дефис-тире

**Приложения** могут писаться через дефис, например *девушка-красавица, роза-цветок.*

А что делать, если в приложении несколько слов? Например:

- Я подошел к своему другу(?)соседу по палате.

Можно поставить запятую, а можно дефис/тире? Если да, то что? Нужны ли пробелы?

Другой пример из `Технического Регламента Таможенного Союза 022/2011`:

- 11. Единый знак обращения продукции на рынке государств - членов Таможенного союза

В законодательстве регистр, конечно, очень формальный, но язык-то все тот же — русский. Здесь почему-то дефис отбит пробелами.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**О первом предложении** (два варианта пунктуации)

По основному правилу *распространенное* приложение, выраженное нарицательным существительным с зависимыми словами и относящееся к нарицательному существительному (обычно такое приложение стоит после определяемого слова, реже — впереди него), обособляется.
Пишем с запятой:
**Я подошел к своему другу, соседу по палате.**

При обособлении приложений вместо запятой употребляется тире перед распространенным или одиночным приложением, стоящим в конце предложения, если подчеркивается самостоятельность приложения либо дается разъяснение: *Путь мой шёл мимо бердской слободы — пристанища пугачёвского* (А. Пушкин).
Пишем с тире:
**Я подошел к своему другу — соседу по палате.**

Был у него закадычный друг ― сосед Василий. [А. С. Новиков-Прибой. Капитан первого ранга (1936-1944)]

**О втором предложении** (один вариант — тире с пробелами)

**Единый знак обращения продукции на рынке государств — членов Таможенного союза**
Пишем без точки в том случае, если это заголовок или подпись (под фотографией, рисунком или другим изображением).

[§ 19. Обособленные приложения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=108#pp108) (Розенталь)
[ЕАС](https://novo-sibirsk.ru/news/256560/)

P. S. Интересно, что в некоторых изданиях предложение, указанное Розенталем в качестве примера, оформлено с запятой (+ "Бердской" написано с прописной буквы).
Это тоже говорит в пользу двоякости пунктуации.

[Путь мой шел мимо Бердской слободы, пристанища пугачевского](https://ilibrary.ru/text/107/p.11/index.html)

Answer (score -1):

Если нужно соединить дефисом слово и фразу, то употребляется тире с пробелами.

Вопрос № 279916
Подскажите, пожалуйста, через дефис или тире? *Женщина - капитан дальнего плавания; компания - оператор электронных платежей.*
Например, в контексте: *По заказу компании оператора электронных платежей эту работу выполнила Нина Евсеева - первая женщина-капитан дальнего плавания*.

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

В сочетаниях с приложением, **если одна из частей содержит пробел**, вместо дефиса должен употребляться знак **тире**: *женщина-капитан*, но *женщина – капитан дальнего плавания*; *компания-оператор*, но *компания – оператор электронных платежей*.